# Compilation Error regarding Variadic Argument in Preproc Parameters in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hi the Stackoverflow community,

I'm trying to compile the following code in the [Visual Studio C++ 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-visual-studio-2022?view=vs-2022) compiler. Here's my code,

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
#define dbg(x...) 
 
int main() {
 
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the code above can be [compiled with gcc  8.3](https://ideone.com/veWIOx). However, if you use Visual Studio 2022 C++ compiler you will get the following error:

```
main.cpp(?): error C2010: '.': unexpected in macro parameter list
```

My question is the following. How can we find an equivalent solution to the problem such that I can compile under VS2022 C++? Thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/variadic-macros?view=msvc-170 seems like thats not allowed

Comment: As you can see this is not permitted in Standard C++ - live - https://godbolt.org/z/8YoGrczxh "_warning: named variadic macros are a GNU extension [-Wvariadic-macros] "_

Comment: The syntax described in [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) requires the ellipsis to be placed either following the parameters list and a comma, or just by itself (i.e., without any other parameters).